# In which method methods should game state be saved/loaded

Tags: save, libgdx, resume

There are a lot of articles about how to save a state of a game and they are pretty good. But I have one conceptual misunderstanding where should I save the state?

My libGDX game has number of screens and pair of them are *MainMenuScreen* and *MainSceneScreen* these are inherited from *Screen* class. *MainMenuScreen* is shown at start of the game the *MainSceneScreen* little later.

What is the problem? I navigated to *MainSceneScreen*, forced Android to stop the application (I change a language settings on the device to achieve this). After that I select the application again and I can see *MainMenuScreen* is shown. But I want *MainSceneScreen* to be shown.

I suppose I should override `resume` method. But which one? I have class *PsGame* that extends *Game* class of libgdx. I put breakpoints to its `resume` method and  it turned out that method was not called. I investigated the problem and I've found this strange code in the `onResume` method of  *AndroidApplication* class in libGDX:

```
    if (!firstResume)
        graphics.resume();
    else
        firstResume = false;
```

My debugger said *firstResume* was true and didn't go to *graphics.resume()* line.

1. What did I do wrong?
2. What methods should I override?

Comment: Try post your Q at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead :)

Comment: LOL - you already did that :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've narrowed this down correctly, and you should be restoring your saved state during the `resume` method call on your `Game` subclass.  This should be called if you switch to some other app for a bit, and then switch back to your app (without going through the steps that will cause the app to be terminated).  For whatever reason, libgdx does not forward the `resume` call for the initial startup (this design is probably a good idea in the long run, but is a bit confusing when starting out).  Its easy enough to invoke your restore code from the `create` method in your `Game` (which is only invoked at application startup) to get the first start of your game to have 'resume' behavior.